# Difference between char[N] and char (&)[N] in parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code doesn't compile:

```
template <int N>
void f(char[N]) {}

int main() {
  char buf[10];
  f(buf);
}
```

If I change the `char[N]` to `char (&)[N]`, it works. So what the difference between them?

Comment: The first line is the same as `template <int N> void f(char *) {}` after *adjustment*, and then there is no way to deduce `N` from the call.   No adjustment applies to `char(&)[N]`, so `N` can be deduced.

Comment: @M.M Exactly. In cases where the template parameter cannot be deduced, including this one, one can always explicitly provide it. Cf. My answer.

Comment: Why not use a std::array as argument instead?

Comment: @M.M: That information belongs in the _answer_ section.

Comment: Now I understand the problem and all the answers below make sense. It is really a hard decision which one to accept.

Answer (score 7):

You have been bitten by backwards compatibility with C.  When you declare a function like:

```
int f(char c[10]);
```

You declare a function whose argument is of type `char *`.  The compiler decays the argument type for you.  The problem is:

```
int f(char c[5]);
```

declares the *same* function.  This is the way C worked, and C++ retained it for compatability.

```
int f(char (&c)[10]);
```

Declares a function whose argument is of type "reference to array (length 10) of char".  C didn't have references, so there is no need to maintain backwards compatibility.

```
int f(char (&c)[5]);
```

Declares a *different* function - with a different argument type.

Comment: In itself, your explanation doesn't go as far as explaining the compilation failure, which is about template argument deduction.

Answer (score 2):

obviously you are aware that `char [N]` is an array and `char (&)[N]` is a reference to a `char [N]`.

c-style arrays are special when passed as arguments by value. The array itself is not passed, but a reference is.

This 'magic' is an historic side-effect of c++'s evolution from C.

to pass an array by value these days we'd use `std::array<char, N>` which encapsulates the c-style array.

note that `char (&)[N]` is treated as a literal type and so may be passed to `constexpr` functions in constexpr context.

Comment: *"The array itself is not passed, but a reference is."* - reference being a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @LogicStuff it will certainly decay to a pointer if necessary but it's actually a reference to an object and (crucially for template deduction) carries type information - including the length of the array.

Comment: "c-style arrays are special when passed as arguments by value": Yes -- because they simply never are.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider perhaps my wording is off. Will rethink.

Answer (score 2):

I think the order of events is

- The compiler *does not* look for a function taking an `char[10]` proper because the language doesn't support passing arrays as values.
- The compiler looks for a function taking a *reference to `char[10]`* (and doesn't find any).
- The compiler looks for a function taking a pointer to `char`, which is the actual argument type after what's called *type adjustment*, and doesn't find any.

The last point is interesting because the template function `f` actually *does take a pointer to char*, as other posters explained: the index in the declaration is superfluous, and in a function declaration `f(char p[])`  `p` is not of type array but of type pointer to char. Note that that differs from declarations of that kind elsewhere (not as a function parameter), where `p` would be an array, albeit incomplete.

The reason the compiler cannot instantiate the function template is not that its argument type is wrong: It would match after argument type adjustment. The reason is simply that **it cannot deduce the template parameter `N` from the argument.** After all, for each `N`  there would be a different `f`: which one should the compiler take?? After the actual argument `buf`  has been "adjusted" to a pointer to its first element, the length information in the argument is lost. (Yes, compilers are stupid.)

The length information was retained when you declared the function as taking a reference to an array.

Another possibility is to simply instantiate the template function explicitly:

`f<10>(buf);` works.